# A trigger that show the user that has made an insertion

Tags: oracle, trigger, users

I have the following code

```
create table o_c(
op_id NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
n_c VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
op VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
amount NUMBER(9,2)
);

create table a_o(
a_id NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
details VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL
);

create sequence a_o_seq
START WITH     1
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

And I need a trigger that writes in "details" of each record this message:

User *username* performed an insert operation. The data added were saved with op_id = *value*, the operation was performed on the date *DATE*

Comment: This forum is to provide help on issues/errors in your code, not to write code for you. Please show your effort and request to help in rectifying the code or with performance improvement.

Comment: And where is the trigger supposed to write this message?  The _information_ (not the specific text you indicate) can be captured by standard AUDIT functions.  No need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Google is there for helping you out in coding. Take this as a challenge start coding , it will help you out more than someone writing it for you. Have a nice day.